# Add persistence.xml file in Maven project from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, persistence.xml

How to add persistence.xml file in Maven project from IntelliJ Idea?

I am using IntelliJ Idea 12 and have created maven project with two modules.
Suppose, ModuleA (parent-maven) and ModuleB (child-maven). I want to add persistence.xml file into the ModuleB.

Can anybody help me for this, because I could not find any window to add persistence.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you look for a place to add specific file,
in the module(On META-INF folder) `right mouse click->New->File`
Name: `persistence.xml`

Make sure you have created that file in META-INF folder which will go to `yourprojectFolder\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\persistence.xml` when you deploy to the server.

Good and easy place to put is you put this `META-INF\persistence.xml` in your source folder(src?)

Comment: sorry, but no folder named META-INF is there when I created either of the module (parent/child). Do I have to create it manually? Doesn't just idea creates the time when I create a new module?

Answer (score 0):

The persistence.xml file should be located in the following path:

\src\main\resources\META-INF\persistence.xml